# Are discrete wavelet transform based statistical features invariant to rotation/translation/scale?

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, machine-learning, statistics, feature-extraction

I'm reading a paper where image classification is done. Their approach is to use the discrete wavelet transform with bi-orthogonal wavelets of degree 3.5 and decomposition of level 3 on images. Based on the 2d coefficients gotten from the DWT they calculate statistical features such as standard deviation, skew, kurtosis, mean, absolute deviation. These statistical features are used as input for classification.

My question is now, are these statistical features based on the DWT rotation/scale/translation invariant ? I personally do not think so. But I can't motivate my answer. Can someone explain this, I'd appreciate if you can quote a source if you anwer.

Comment: are the wavelets symmetrical?  I don't think it could be rotation-invariant otherwise

Comment: Yes bior3.5 wavelets are symmetric: http://wavelets.pybytes.com/wavelet/bior3.5/

Comment: It will depend of the wavelet family of course but I would say mostly no either. See stationary wavelet transform and scattering transform (http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~mallat/papiers/ScatCPAM.pdf).

Comment: Can you please give the exact mathematical expression of at least one of the features they calculate?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac this is the paper I am talking about: http://www.buet.ac.bd/me/icme2013/icme2009/Proceedings/PDF/ICME09-RT-39.pdf . The statistical features are: Skew, Kurtosis, Mean absolute deviation, Mean, Entropy and standard deviation

Comment: I find it surprising that this paper has passed peer review. It is very hard to tell how exactly they calculate their features as there are details they are omitting. In any case, if you want transformation invariant features from a wavelet transform you should formulate them as expectation values of linear operators, and the operators must commute with the generators of the symmetry you want them to be invariant under. This is the most general class of symmetric features I can think of, and basis independent by construction.